# "Failed to compile the generated registrar code." After updating Forms and Visual.Material to v4.2.0.848062

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Following, is the section of my output where it errors out. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xcode 11 to build. I have cleaned and built. Removed bin/obj from projects to make sure it wasn't that and after looking at the output file, it seems something to do with files I have never touched.

```
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++  -Wno-receiver-forward-class -Wno-objc-missing-super-calls -Wno-unguarded-availability-new -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.4.0.64/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -arch arm64 -c -o /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o -x objective-c++ -DDEBUG /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.m
3>  In file included from /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:3:
3>  In file included from /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.h:19:
3>  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/Photos.h:31:
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHImageManager.h:17:47: error: expected identifier or '{'
3>  typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation);
3>                                                ^ 
3>  /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:12096:17: warning: method 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController:' in protocol 'UISearchResultsUpdating' not implemented [-Wprotocol]
3>  @implementation UIKit_UISearchController___Xamarin_UISearchResultsUpdating {
3>                  ^ 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISearchController.h:33:1: note: method 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController:' declared here
3>  - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;
3>  ^ 
3>  /Users/jbarrientos/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ILSMobile.iOS/03074acfdcf196377abbb6532e618958/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:12096:17: warning: method 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController:' in protocol 'UISearchResultsUpdating' not implemented [-Wprotocol]
3>  @implementation UIKit_UISearchController___Xamarin_UISearchResultsUpdating {
3>                  ^ 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISearchController.h:33:1: note: method 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController:' declared here
3>  - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;
3>  ^ 
3>  2 warnings and 1 error generated.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building with the a lower iOS SDK Version and using a type introduced in iOS a later one.

You need build with the latest SDK (iOS 13), you can select this in your
project's iOS Build options).

If you don't find it, you should update the Xamarin.iOS on your Mac machine!

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm running this on my windows machine paired to my mac. I updated the field "SDK Versions:" to 13.0. It was originally "Default", but it still gives me the same issue. Let me know if you need the full output.

Comment: I'm actually updating my xamarin.iOS on my mac. When I tried to pair it again on my windows machine it said that the version of VS I had did not support it :( I have 17 so it looks like I need to upgrade to VS 19.

Comment: Sigh, yeah hopefully we wont have these issues for long! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-hot-restart/  “With Hot Restart you can debug your iOS app built with Xamarin.Forms on a device connected to your Windows machine allowing for a much faster inner development loop compared to today”

Comment: I'm getting the same error after my MAC build server upgraded to xcode 13.0.  Is there a workaround?  I saw this that said there was a new version coming. Not sure if that fixes it.  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7047

Comment: Patrick! They already released the Xamarin iOS version mentioned in that Github issue. I would not recommend switching to the preview build as it could cause other issues. Are you using any other preview build of anything or a beta version of Catalina?

Comment: Ok thanks.  I haven't gotten that version yet.  I'm using the following:  Xamarin   16.2.0.90, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 12.14.0.110, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.2.0. Should I get that latest version?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend updating to what ever the latest version is available in the Stable build channel

Comment: I went to Visual Studio 19 because 17 did not support the new version of xamarin.ios and a few other ones. After updating to 19 I was able to compile and run the app with no issues @PatrickGoode

Comment: Yep same here.  It works after upgrading to the latest VS and Xamarin